# Where object based on a variable content

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with this Office365 Powershell script

```
$expireUser = Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false}

$expireUser | ft DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, PasswordNeverExpires

$userinput = Read-Host 'Users in the table have the parameter PasswordNeverExpires set on $False. Set to $True? (Y/N)'
If ($userinput -eq "Y"){
    Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false} | Set-MsolUser -PasswordNeverExpires $True
    write-host "Down are visible the parameters of the users modified." 
    $expireUserCheck =  Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.UserPrincipalName -eq $expireUser.UserPrincipalName}
    $expireUserCheck | ft DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, PasswordNeverExpires
    }
Elseif ($userinput -eq "N")
    {write-host "No change are made"}
Else    
    {write-host "Input not managed"}
```

The process of change the parameters works everytime correct so the basic function of the script are ok but  the problem is that only if 1 user have the parameter set the check works showing me the table with the DisplayName, the UserPrincipalName and $True under PasswordNeverExpire.
If 2 or more user are in $expireUser variable nothing appears when the second table must be show.

Any idea?

Many thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an array of UserPrincipalNames by using the following:

```
$arrayOfuserPrincipalnames = $expireUser | Select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName
```

then change this line:

```
$expireUserCheck =  Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.UserPrincipalName -eq $expireUser.UserPrincipalName}
```

to:

```
$expireUserCheck =  Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.UserPrincipalName -in $arrayOfUserPrincipalnames}
```