# Filter Where-Object on variable property

Tags: powershell

Read the following answers:
([Where object based on a variable content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296358/where-object-based-on-a-variable-content)), ([Use array of strings for comparing in Where-Object in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408185/use-array-of-strings-for-comparing-in-where-object-in-powershell))

```
$allgroups
DisplayName
--------
Group1
Group2
Group3

$mailgroups
DisplayName
--------
Group1
Group3

$newgroup = $allgroups | ? ($_.DisplayName -notin $mailgroups)
$newgroup = $allgroups | ? ($_.DisplayName -notin ($mailgroups | Select DisplayName))
```

$newgroup should = "DisplayName: Group2", above commands return null. Tried other operators:

```
-ne, -cnotin, -eq, -notcontains
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
$newgroup = $allgroups | ? DisplayName -notin $mailgroups.DisplayName
```

or if you want to keep your way:

```
$newgroup = $allgroups | Where-Object { $PSItem.DisplayName -notin $mailgroups.DisplayName }
```

alternatively, for v2:

```
$newgroup = $allgroups | Where-Object {
    ($mailgroups | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName) -notcontains $_.DisplayName
}
```

*footnote: `$PSItem` and `$_` are the same; `$PSItem` introduced in v3. Additionally, `?` is the default alias for `Where-Object`.*

Comment: Perfect, realized my mistake substituting () for {}. Thank you!

Comment: @009 Great, if my answer solved your problem, kindly vote on it and mark it as the answer.